# Как сделать, чтобы код работал для все классов?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, чтобы данный код применялся ко всем `.productdetails`?

```js
    const ul = document.querySelector('.productdetails');

    const data = [...ul.children].reduce((acc, n) => {
      const k = n.innerText[0].toLowerCase();
      (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(n.outerHTML);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    const html = Object
      .entries(data)
      .map(([ k, v ]) => `<div class="hua-rotate">${k}</div><ul class="${k}-litter">${v.join('')}</ul></div>`)
      .join('');

    ul.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
    ul.remove();
```

```html
<ul class="productdetails">
 <li><a>Acer</a></li>
  <li><a>Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="productdetails">
 <li><a>Acer</a></li>
  <li><a>Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пример в снипете сделайте рабочим, я не понял, что у вас не работает

Comment: @doox911 обновил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что то типо этого ?

```js
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('.productdetails');
[].forEach.call(ul, (item) => {
    const data = [...item.children].reduce((acc, n) => {
    let t = n.innerText.indexOf(' ') != -1 ? n.innerText.split(' ')[1] : n.innerText;
    let k = t[0].toLowerCase();
    (acc[k] = acc[k] || []).push(t);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const html = Object
    .entries(data)
    .map(([ k, v ]) => `<div class="hua-rotate">${k}</div><ul class="${k}-litter">${v.join('')}</ul></div>`)
    .join('');

  item.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
  item.remove();
});
```

```html
<ul class="productdetails">
 <li><a>Заголовок Acer</a></li>
  <li><a>Заголовок Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li><a>Заголовок Samsung</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="productdetails">
 <li><a>Acer</a></li>
  <li><a>Xiaomi</a></li>
    <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а можно вместо первого слова взять второе слово от li?

Comment: У меня есть данный код, но я пока что не слишком опытен, чтобы совместить их 
`const secondWords = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('h3'),
  h => h.innerText.split(' ')[1],
);`

Comment: Не совсем понял, у вас же там только 1 слово, планируется что будет 2  и нужно будет только второе ?

Comment: Вы верно поняли задание, просто немного изменилась ситуация и я спросил в комментариях  учетом нового условия

Comment: Я поправил ответ, сейчас код работает как с 1 словом так и с 2-мя

Comment: И последний вопрос, если можно. Данный скрипт вырезает текст заголовка и потом подставляет его в указанный в скрипте HTML-код. А можно было бы сделать так, чтобы вырезалось не слово, а полностью `<li>`

Comment: До сих пор не получается написать правильный код. Ели Вас не затруднит, помогите, пожалуйста